# C++. Accumulate binary array to integer by using custom lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

How can I accumulate a binary array containing 0 and 1 into an integer?

```
vector<int> arr = {1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0};

int num = accumulate(
    arr.begin(), arr.end(), 
    [](int &a, int &b)
    { 
        // ???  
    }
);
```

At each step I need something like this:

```
if(arr[i] % 2) num += pow(2, i);
```

But how to implement this in lambda? How to get `i` in lambda?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. In `if(i % 2) num += pow(i, 2);` is `i` supposed to be the index into the array? Why does it mater whether the index is odd or even? Why do you want to accumulate squares of an index? Why does this statement never look at actual values in the array - don't they matter for anything? In your particular example, what should the value of `num` be at the end?

Comment: Side note: Avoid `pow(i, 2)` like the plague. `pow` works in floating point numbers and you can get some unfortunate results due to imprecision and rounding. You're generally better off multiplying, but in this case look into bit shifting to place the bit where you want it.

Comment: Side side note: `pow(i, 2)` is square `i`. You wanted `pow(2, i)`. But as above, you don't want it.

Comment: Does `{1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0}` represent `10101110100` or `00101110101`?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Im sorry! My mistake! Of course ```if(arr[i] % 2) num += pow(2, i);```

Comment: @user4581301 Yes, you are right!!! My mistake! Im sorry!

Comment: Why are you taking modulo 2? Does the vector store any values other than 0 or 1? Are you expecting that if it stores a 2, that should be treated as a 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must use a position, you can capture an index variable by reference in your lambda. Of course, the usual caveats about `pow` and floating point numbers apply, and this is unnecessary to accomplish the task, but it is *possible*.

```
int idx = 0;

int number = std::accumulate(
  arr.begin(), arr.end(),
  [&idx](const int num, const int bit) {
    return num + bit * std::pow(2, idx++);
  }
);
```

Avoiding the floating point math involved in `std::pow`:

```
int idx = 0;

int number = std::accumulate(
  arr.begin(), arr.end(),
  [&idx](const int num, const int bit) {
    return num + bit * (1 << (idx++));
  }
);
```

Sidenote: `arr` is a misleading name for a `std::vector` variable.

Keep in mind also that the lambda you pass to `std::accumulate` should not mutate either of its two arguments, but rather just generate a new value.

Comment: Note: it's probably actually _not_, but you're welcome. :)

Comment: Haha yeah this is indeed the worst of all the proposed solutions, despite being technically the answer most faithful to the question!

Comment: @OP NEVER use std::pow (you will get rounding errors), use shift left operator!

Comment: @PepjinKramer, it may be worth clarifying that to mean "never use std::pow in this context."

Comment: In case the OP wants to avoid the `pow` conversion to `double`... `return num + bit * (1 << (idx++));`

Answer (score 7):

My guess is, you are looking either for

```
std::accumulate(arr.begin(), arr.end(), 0,
  [](int acc, int val) { return acc * 2 + val; })
```

or

```
// Note reverse iterators
std::accumulate(arr.rbegin(), arr.rend(), 0,
  [](int acc, int val) { return acc * 2 + val; })
```

depending on whether `arr` is supposed to be ordered from most-significant to least-significant bit, or vice versa.

Answer (score 4):

If you meant `i` to be an intex, you don't need here. In fact the binary to decimal conversion using `std::accumulate` much easier with bit operation.

```
const int result = std::accumulate(arr.rbegin(), arr.rend(), 0,
                                   [](int num, int bit)
                                   {   // Update num based on the position
                                       // of the bit
                                       num = (num << 1) | bit;
                                       return num;
                                   });
```

Example code: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/zqTPaG3z3

Answer (score 2):

> How can I accumulate a binary array containing 0 and 1 into an integer?

If you are willing to use an actual array or `std::array` instead of a `std::vector` as storage, you can do it very efficiently with a fold expression over the `|` operator, so you don't need `std::accumulate` to iterate over the values.

I'm assuming that you could even use a fixed size array of 64 elements to accommodate all the numbers you are planning to convert. You may want to consider using an `unsigned` type for this though, since you do not want to shift a set bit into the sign bit of a signed integer.

Example:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <utility>

namespace detail {
    // helper to construct the fold expression from a pack of indices:
    template<class T, std::size_t... I>
    constexpr auto to_number_helper(const T& arr, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
        return (... | (arr[I] << I));
    }
}

// overload for std::array's
template<class T, std::size_t N>
auto constexpr to_number(const std::array<T, N>& arr) {
    return detail::to_number_helper(arr, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

// overload for traditional C arrays:
template<class T, std::size_t N>
auto constexpr to_number(const T(&arr)[N]) {
    return detail::to_number_helper(arr, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

The fold expression in your case "unfolds" to:

```
(1 << 0 | 0 << 1 | 1 << 2 | 0 << 3 | 1 << 4 | 1 << 5 |
 1 << 6 | 0 << 7 | 1 << 8 | 0 << 9 | 0 << 10)
```

You can then use it like this to get the same result:

```cpp
int main() {    
    constexpr std::array arr1 = {1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0};
    constexpr int arr2[]{1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0};

    constexpr auto result1 = to_number(arr1);
    constexpr auto result2 = to_number(arr2);
 
    // all print 373:   
    std::cout << 0b00101110101 << '\n'
              << result1 << '\n'
              << result2 << '\n'
              << (1 << 0 | 0 << 1 | 1 << 2 | 0 << 3 | 1 << 4 | 1 << 5 |
                  1 << 6 | 0 << 7 | 1 << 8 | 0 << 9 | 0 << 10) << '\n';
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ETb6rooc1)

---

A safer helper function can be made to use, and return, an unsigned type that can accommodate the result depending on the size of your array:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail {
template<size_t N>
using type = std::conditional_t<N<=8, std::uint_least8_t,
             std::conditional_t<N<=16, std::uint_least16_t, 
             std::conditional_t<N<=32, std::uint_least32_t, 
             std::conditional_t<N<=64, std::uint_least64_t, void>>>>;

// helper to construct the fold expression from a pack of indices:
template <class T, std::size_t... I>
constexpr auto to_number_helper(const T& arr, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    using RT = type<sizeof...(I)>; // get a suitable type for the expression
    return (... | (static_cast<RT>(arr[I]) << I));
}
}  // namespace detail
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/KGsnn8Exo)